# Jaspic: handle access to a protected resource

Tags: jakarta-ee, jaspic

I'm (still) studying JASPIC, doing some experiments by simple project: [this one](https://github.com/fpezzati/jaspicrepo/). When I call a protected resources `ServerAuthModule` checks credentials via `validateRequest` and returns `AuthStatus.SUCCESS`. HTTP response is 200 but it is empty. I use these two `curl` commands to test:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"xxx","password":"xxx"}' http://localhost:8080/JaspicWeb/services/user/login
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJleHAiOjE0NzE0NzE1ODcsInN1YiI6InVzZXJBIn0.Gyf7w2192vlz3uSwjwtf8z1p9n9k3IqtQMQrubA7oYI" -X GET http://localhost:8080/JaspicWeb/services/user/userA
```

The first command is to get the token used in the second one. I'm using Jaspic with Wildfly10 and RestEasy.

**Update:**
I updated the linked project. Now it is a full working `Jaspic` example.

Comment: Please provide more information, e.g. the response's status (if you receive one at all) and any relevant log entries. Also, I doubt that you need the `<login-config>` element in your `web.xml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SAM's `CallbackHandler` is the cause of your troubles.

First `it.jaspic.sec.TokenConfigProvider` disregards the handler passed to it by the runtime:

```
public ServerAuthConfig getServerAuthConfig(String layer, String appContext, CallbackHandler handler) throws AuthException {
  return serverAuthConfig;
}
```

Then `it.jaspic.sec.TokenServerConfig` uses its own handler, which basically does nothing:

```
public TokenServerConfig() throws AuthException {
  // ...
  handler = new CallbackHandler() {
    @Override
    public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {
      // just logs its arguments
    }
  };
}
```

Consequently, `it.jaspic.sec.TokenSAM#validateRequest` is unable to communicate the caller's identity to the runtime. Since it still erroneously returns `AuthStatus.SUCCESS` though, it is pretty much undefined behaviour from that point on, at least as far as JASPIC is concerned. It is, amusingly, as if the Servlet container were trying to keep both parties happy in this case, by honoring both the SAM's `AuthStatus` that suggests a successful authentication message exchange, on the one hand, as well as the application's `<security-constraint>` on the other. Admittedly, a `401`, `403`, or perhaps better yet, a `500` response--indicative of an authentication mechanism not obeying its contract--might have been less confusing.

The obvious solution is to pass the *runtime-provided* handler to the SAM. The API clearly doesn't help much, but for the single message layer/single app/single authentication mechanism use case, it should be sufficient to just lazily instantiate the `ServerAuthConfig` *with* the handler, when it is first requested by the runtime via a `getServerAuthConfig` invocation:

```
public synchronized ServerAuthConfig getServerAuthConfig(String layer, String appContext, CallbackHandler handler) {
  if (serverAuthConfig == null) {
    serverAuthConfig = new TokenServerConfig(handler);
  }
  return serverAuthConfig;
}
```

And, of course, the new constructor called above (which only has to store the handler argument) has to be introduced into `it.jaspic.sec.TokenServerConfig`.

Those two changes should render the `/services/user/userA` endpoint accessible.